# Why does Angular provide these seemingly redundant helper functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular provides several helper functions:

- lowercase
- uppercase
- isFunction
- forEach
- Many more

There are native implementations for each of these.  For example, String.prototype.toLowerCase() has existed since ECMAScript First Edition.  Why does Angular provide this seemingly redundant functionality?

Comment: Not all browsers support some of the methods you listed.

Comment: Why do you have it in jquery? Same reason for angular..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dig into Angular's code base, you'll notice that the utility functions defined in [angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js) are used quite frequently. While certain function definitions in angular's set of utility functions do seem rather redundant, there are a few benefits in having them defined this way:

1. Some of the utility functions do have subtle behavioral differences when compared to their native counterparts. For instance, just looking at the documentation for Angular's `angular.forEach`:

> - Unlike ES262's Array.prototype.forEach,
>
>   - Providing 'undefined' or 'null' values for `obj` will not throw a TypeError, but rather just return the value provided.
>       
>       `var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
>       var log = [];
>       angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
>       this.push(key + ': ' + value);
>       }, log);
>       expect(log).toEqual(['name: misko', 'gender: male']);`
>       
>       *

2. Type-verification calls such as `angular.isDate` can be replaced by their defining expression `toString.call(value) === '[object Date]'` without too much fuss, but having a single function call like `angular.isDate` presents a more fluent interface to other parts of the code base.

   i.e. the expression

   `if (angular.isDate(value)) { /* do work */ }`

   is easier to read and understand than its counterpart

   `if (toString.call(value) === '[object Date]') { /* do work */ }`
3. Centralizing the implementation of their utility functions also allows Angular [to easily test](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/AngularSpec.js) these functions, to ensure that they behave as expected across different browser implementations. Other parts of the Angular code base can then call this set of tested utility functions, knowing that, in theory,  each call should behave in a predictable way.

I'm sure there are many other reasons that I haven't thought of, but you can always dive into the code base yourself to get a better, more complete answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Some on these are inexistant in JavaScript 1.5, other are wrapper around native function.

For instance, [lowercase](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.11/src/Angular.js#L127) is a wrapper around `String.prototype.toLowerCase()` and prevents exception when called on non-string object.